# How to group files in array of objects deponds on the number of pages of each one

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, group-by

I've got an array of objects:
*Input*

```js
[
  { file: '1.pdf', text: 'Page: 1 / 2' },
  { file: '2.pdf', text: 'Page: 2 / 2' },
    // -- '1.pdf':['1.pdf','2.pdf']
  { file: '3.pdf', text: 'Page: 1 / 3' },
  { file: '4.pdf', text: 'Page: 2 / 3' },
  { file: '5.pdf', text: 'Page: 3 / 3' },
    // -- '2.pdf':['3.pdf','4.pdf', '5.pdf']
  { file: '6.pdf', text: 'Page: 1 / 4' },
  { file: '7.pdf', text: 'Page: 2 / 4' },
  { file: '8.pdf', text: 'Page: 3 / 4' },
  { file: '9.pdf', text: 'Page: 4 / 4' }
    // -- '3.pdf':['6.pdf','7.pdf', '8.pdf', '9.pdf']
]
```

And I wanna group them deponds on the number of pages of each one like this *Output*:

```js
{
  "1.pdf": ["1.pdf", "2.pdf"],
  "2.pdf": ["3.pdf", "4.pdf", "5.pdf"],
  "3.pdf": ["6.pdf", "7.pdf", "8.pdf", "9.pdf"],
};
```

My Attempt:

```js
let arr = [
  { file: "1.pdf", text: "Page: 1 / 2" },
  { file: "2.pdf", text: "Page: 2 / 2" },
  { file: "3.pdf", text: "Page: 1 / 3" },
  { file: "4.pdf", text: "Page: 2 / 3" },
  { file: "5.pdf", text: "Page: 3 / 3" },
  { file: "6.pdf", text: "Page: 1 / 4" },
  { file: "7.pdf", text: "Page: 2 / 4" },
  { file: "8.pdf", text: "Page: 3 / 4" },
  { file: "9.pdf", text: "Page: 4 / 4" },
];
let result = {};
let i = 0;
let x = null;
let visited = [];
for (const { file, text } of arr) {
  let val = text.split("/").at(-1).trim();
  let key = null;
  if (!visited.includes(val)) {
    key = ++i + ".pdf";
    x = key;
    visited.push(val);
  } else {
    key = x;
  }
  result[key] ??= [];
  result[key].push(file);
}

console.log(result);
```

This works well in case where there's **unique** *number of pages*, **BUT** When there's the same *number of pages* on other it fails and combines them all to one instead of create new one:

```js
[
  { file: '1.pdf', text: 'Page: 1 / 2' },
  { file: '2.pdf', text: 'Page: 2 / 2' },
  { file: '3.pdf', text: 'Page: 1 / 3' },
  { file: '4.pdf', text: 'Page: 2 / 3' },
  { file: '5.pdf', text: 'Page: 3 / 3' },
  { file: '6.pdf', text: 'Page: 1 / 4' },
  { file: '7.pdf', text: 'Page: 2 / 4' },
  { file: '8.pdf', text: 'Page: 3 / 4' },
  { file: '9.pdf', text: 'Page: 4 / 4' },
  { file: '10.pdf', text: 'Page: 1 / 2' },
  { file: '11.pdf', text: 'Page: 2 / 2' },
]
```

*Output*:

```js
{
  "1.pdf": ["1.pdf", "2.pdf"],
  "2.pdf": ["3.pdf", "4.pdf", "5.pdf"], //      vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
  "3.pdf": ["6.pdf", "7.pdf", "8.pdf", "9.pdf", "10.pdf", "11.pdf"],
};
```

*Expected Output*:

```js
{
  "1.pdf": ["1.pdf", "2.pdf"],
  "2.pdf": ["3.pdf", "4.pdf", "5.pdf"],
  "3.pdf": ["6.pdf", "7.pdf", "8.pdf", "9.pdf"],
  "4.pdf": ["10.pdf", "11.pdf"],
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### CODE

```
var array = [
  { file: '1.pdf', text: 'Page: 1 / 2' },
  { file: '2.pdf', text: 'Page: 2 / 2' },
  { file: '3.pdf', text: 'Page: 1 / 3' },
  { file: '4.pdf', text: 'Page: 2 / 3' },
  { file: '5.pdf', text: 'Page: 3 / 3' },
  { file: '6.pdf', text: 'Page: 1 / 4' },
  { file: '7.pdf', text: 'Page: 2 / 4' },
  { file: '8.pdf', text: 'Page: 3 / 4' },
  { file: '9.pdf', text: 'Page: 4 / 4' },
  { file: '10.pdf', text: 'Page: 1 / 2' },
  { file: '11.pdf', text: 'Page: 2 / 2' },
];

var ret = {};
var lastGroup = 0;

array.forEach(function (value, i) {
    if(value.text.includes("Page: 1 /")){
        lastGroup++;
        ret[lastGroup + ".pdf"]=[];
    }
    ret[lastGroup + ".pdf"].push(value.file);
});

console.log(ret);
```

### OUTPUT

```
{
  "1.pdf": [
    "1.pdf",
    "2.pdf"
  ],
  "2.pdf": [
    "3.pdf",
    "4.pdf",
    "5.pdf"
  ],
  "3.pdf": [
    "6.pdf",
    "7.pdf",
    "8.pdf",
    "9.pdf"
  ],
  "4.pdf": [
    "10.pdf",
    "11.pdf"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Don't just provide a block of code. Explain what you have done and how it addresses the OP's question. Include links to relevant documentation when appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to iterate over the array of objects, writing a new value to the output whenever we encounter a `Page: 1` or at the end of the array:

```js
const arr = [
  { file: '1.pdf', text: 'Page: 1 / 2' },
  { file: '2.pdf', text: 'Page: 2 / 2' },
  { file: '3.pdf', text: 'Page: 1 / 3' },
  { file: '4.pdf', text: 'Page: 2 / 3' },
  { file: '5.pdf', text: 'Page: 3 / 3' },
  { file: '6.pdf', text: 'Page: 1 / 4' },
  { file: '7.pdf', text: 'Page: 2 / 4' },
  { file: '8.pdf', text: 'Page: 3 / 4' },
  { file: '9.pdf', text: 'Page: 4 / 4' },
  { file: '10.pdf', text: 'Page: 1 / 2' },
  { file: '11.pdf', text: 'Page: 2 / 2' },
]

const result = arr.reduce(({ fnum, pages, files }, { file, text }, i, a) => {
  const pgnum = text.match(/Page: (\d+)/)[1]
  if (i == a.length - 1) {
    pages.push(file)
    files[`${++fnum}.pdf`] = pages
    return files
  }
  else if (pgnum == 1 && pages.length) {
    files[`${++fnum}.pdf`] = pages
    pages = [file]
  }
  else {
    pages.push(file)
  }
  return { fnum, pages, files }
}, { fnum : 0, pages : [], files : {} });

console.log(result)
```